# React chartjs-2 - Increase spacing between legend and chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am using `react chartjs 2`. I need to increase margin between legend and chart. Here I found many solutions that are not for react or nextjs. That's why I need to solve it with react environment. Please help me.

Here is my code-

```
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
} from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
    Legend
);

const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                boxHeight: 2,
                boxWidth: 50
            },
        },
    }
};

const data = {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: 'iPhone',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};

const DownloadChart = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <Typography variant="h5" component="h5">
                Device Download
            </Typography>
            <Line
                datasetIdKey='id'
                data={data}
                options={options}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
export default DownloadChart;
```

I see that there are available beforeInit and afterInit function. But I am not knowing that How can I apply it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom plugin:

```js
ChartJS.register({
  id: 'customSpacingLegend',
  beforeInit(chart) {
    // Get reference to the original fit function
    const originalFit = chart.legend.fit;

    // Override the fit function
    chart.legend.fit = function fit() {
      // Call original function and bind scope in order to use `this` correctly inside it
      originalFit.bind(chart.legend)();
      // Change the height as suggested in another answers
      this.height += 15;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Class doesn't have id. Giving this error!

Comment: mb, updated answer

Comment: Work perfect , thanks a lot ! At least now i know where to put beforeInit or afterInit !